# Phonology: Exemplars vs. Abstract Phoneme Theory

Tags: phonology, phonemes, generative-grammar, chomsky

I have come across an essay title asking us to critique the evidence of language being processed as either “abstract phonemes” or “surface exemplars”. (Specifically in phonology)
Is this a rewording of the debate between OT vs RBT? Rules vs. constraints? Generativism/Chomsky vs. ? ? 
I feel lost with what to plan.

Could anyone clarify the actual “standard” names of the relevant theories or point towards any particular papers?

Would anyone be able to outline the two opposing sides? There seem to be so many different terms thrown around that it is difficult to split everything into two opposing sides.

Thanks for any input you have, as I have been searching for literally weeks.

Comment: The word phoneme himself means an abstract or cognitive reality in comparison to phonetic which is the study of the physical reality of the language. So talking about "abstract phoneme" is a pleonasm.

Comment: I cannot articulate how much that elucidates the question! Thank you

Comment: (Any further comments would be much appreciated)

Comment: It would seem that "processed" is the key word. Children learning to speak are confronted not with abstract phonemes but with surface exemplars of the language they eventually come to speak. After they become speakers, they presumably have an abstract phoneme system that allows them to make up exemplars appropriately as needed.

Comment: That is an interesting point. It seems almost as though the “exemplar theory” side will have to argue that children store new words’ pronunciation without any “compression” – which in itself sounds to be a challenging stance to defend.

Comment: The use of relevant scientific terminology is the basis of science. When someone uses terms which he doesn't understand, it is likely that all what it can write is doubtful.

Comment: Here is the paper: https://ling.auf.net/lingbuzz/004131/current.pdf?_s=Bkvd8S7hwEszXvT2

Comment: Yes, I think the essay question’s wording is misleading in this way (as is the plethora of literature using different terminology for seemingly the same concepts). There seems to be a fair amount of usage variation with terms such as “abstract”, “token”, “exemplar”, etc.

Comment: Many thanks for that paper: it is precisely the type of material I have been searching for.

Answer (score 1):

All of the terminology that you propose is "the same" in fundamental ways that make those theories distinct from Exemplar Theory.

The hard part for you will be figuring out what "exemplar theory" says, as applied to phonology. Outside of exemplar theoretic approaches (there are many of them), *everybody* has "abstract phonemes", that is some kind of mental representation of sound. In fact, an exemplar is also a mental representation (the only thing that isn't abstract is an actual waveform, and you don't have them in your head); it's just claimed to be *less* abstract.

Indeed, it is not clear that exemplar approaches are "phonology" in the same sense that OT or rule-based theory is, that is, it may not be a theory of how to compute Arabic verb inflection (Arabic has an interestingly complex set of alternations, often called "morphophonology" because it is phonology connected to morphological differences such as the different effects of adding the endings /t,na/ versus /at,aw/ to /bana/: [baneet, baneena] vs. [banat, banaw]). Exemplar theory seems to address the question "how are you likely to actually pronounce this word", rather that "what is the form of the 3rd pl perfective of 'build'?". That is, EP and generic computational theories of phonology with phonemes are about different things. EP focuses on things like child language acquisition, accommodation to dialect and individual differences and production variation. Grammatical theories may indeed embrace those sorts of phenomena. Frequently, people point to some fact of child language or slips of the tongue to support their claimed generalization. Some people e.g. Hale and Reiss and numerous others distinguish between facts about grammar – phonology – versus speech and performance – phonetics, maybe.

Probably the best reference for applying exemplar theory to phonology is [this paper by Johnson](http://linguistics.berkeley.edu/phonlab/documents/2005/Johnson_decisions289-311.pdf).

Comment: Fascinating ideas; thank you very much for your reply. The crossover into morphology is interesting and indeed, as you, say a challenge when instructed to remain within the phonological realm.

Comment: I wonder whether you or anyone else would be able to point me in the direction of some exemplar theory papers/literature/authors, for finding some of the proposed evidence?

Comment: It seems that "surface" is simply a synonym of morphology, it is not opposed necessarily to phoneme.

Comment: I'm trying to make sense of the Johnson paper you referred us to.  No luck, so far.

Answer (score 1):

I hear tell that young children sometimes get mad at adults who talk to them in child speech, because they can tell they're being made fun of.  Adult says "And do we hear the fwoggy cwoaking?", and child betrays signs of irritation: "No, it's not fwoggy.  It's fwoggy!"

If this happens, it suggests that we don't even hear surface exemplars, usually.

Comment: Fair point you make. I came across a similar set of examples in “Words in the Mind” by Jean Aitchison but had never made this connection. Perhaps it could also spark discussion on perceptive phonemic boundaries (e.g. do we recognize the [w] in “fwoggy” as an allophone of the /r/ as in “froggy”, or is it perceived as within the boundary of the one phone [ɹ] and therefore as the same sound? Unless both of the aforementioned qualify as “allophone” phenomena...)

Comment: @tiredstudent I would say, no. We recognize it as disordered speech. We recognize that the speaker uses the wrong phoneme. In this case even the child seems to recognize that but it hasn't mastered the articulation (the perception is ahead). Or the child still makes some distinction that we don't perceive and the child's phone is an allophone of /ɹ/ for the child but an allophone of /w/ for us whereas the adult's [w] is an allophone of /w/ for both the adult and the child.